# Checking values of objects from root to desired child

Tags: c#

So i have an object filled with many inner objects. To get a value of inner object that i want to know i must first check if all parents all the way to root object are not null. Code looks like this:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
//Wanted object can be even deeper
if (root != null &&
    root.InnerObject1 != null &&
    root.InnerObject1.InnerObject2 != null &&
    root.InnerObject1.InnerObject2.InnerObject3 != null &&
    root.InnerObject1.InnerObject2.InnerObject3.value != null)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(root.InnerObject1.InnerObject2.InnerObject3.value)
}
```

Can this be done in more elegant way?

Comment: Your properties are named with numbers? or is this just for demo?

Comment: its just a demo. I currently use object Camt054 statement. Some sample can be found here https://wiki.xmldation.com/General_Information/ISO_20022/Payments_Maintenance_camt053,_camt.054,_camt.052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With current C# version: **no**.
With the next one: yes.

C# 6 will have a new feature called null-conditional operator designed for cases like this. It will let you write

```
var value = root?.InnerObject2?.InnerObject2?.InnerObject3?.value;
if(value != null)
    stringBuilder.Append(value);
```

Comment: You can use it if you install Visual Studio 2015, which is still in beta state, but have C# features implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Why not introduce:

```
private static bool NestedElementAvailable(Node startNode, int depth)
{
     Node node = startNode
     while(node != null && depth > 0)
     {
        node = node.InnerNode;
        depth--;
     }
     return depth == 0 && node != null && node.Value != null;
}
```

Edit:

```
private static bool SomeSeriousNameForCondition(Node node)
{
    return //the condition
}
```

Then in the orignial code

```
if(SomeSeriousNameForCondition(root))
```

I know this does not reduce the code but at least its more readable.

Comment: you may need one more condition in your return statement that `node != null` before checking `node.Value != null`

Comment: You can reprogram this to get the value and puts it into an out parameter... like tryparse

Comment: How can i deal with the InnerNode name though? The object is more of a tree so there can be more nested elements in each one.

Comment: So you got a path to the goalnode or something?

Comment: Yes I have the whole path.

Comment: In that case the only way i see without c#6 and without a terrible try catch block is to refactor the condition to a method.

Comment: The only other way i see is write decorators(or adapters or wrappers) for the classes implementing a method to return the string you want. you only posted a small snippet so i cant see clearly if that could be applied to your problem

Comment: So basically putting my condition into one method? While its not a bad idea, i need to get about 30 values out of root, so that would mean one method for each desired object value.

Comment: The object i currently work with is in the comments below question. I can put it into original question if you want.

Comment: I got an appointment to a microsoft exam soon or i would look into it right now. By the way i cannot see any comments on this linked webpage. guess you have to be registered or something.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test root = new Test
        {
            Property1 = new Test { Value = 3 },
            Property2 = new Test { Value = 4 },
            Property3 = new Test { Property1 = new Test { Value = 4} }
        };
        int testValue1;
        if (root.TryGetData<int>(out testValue1,"Property1","Value"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(testValue1);
        }
        int testValue2;
        if (root.TryGetData<int>(out testValue2, "Property2","Property1","Value" ))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would be bad if this would enter here");
        }
        if (root.TryGetData<int>(out testValue2, "Property3", "Property1", "Value"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(testValue2);
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    public Test Property1 { get; set; }
    public Test Property2 { get; set; }
    public Test Property3 { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool TryGetData<T>(this object theObject, out T value, params string[] path)
    {
        object cursor = theObject;

        for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cursor == null)
            {
                value = default(T);
                return false;
            }
            Type t = cursor.GetType();
            cursor = t.GetProperty(path[i]).GetValue(cursor);
        }
        value = (T)cursor;
        return true;
    }
}
```

It's by no means good practise but it would get the job done.